# Get file over bluetooth

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth

I need to build an Android app capable to get a particular file - for which I know the path - from a remote device via Bluetooth.

I managed to establish a connection between the two devices (they're paired) and thus to send a file.

Is there any similar way to download a file? How would this be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement Bluetooth FTP profile and achieve what you wanted .

Comment: Isn't there a simpler way to achieve this? Or do you have a link that explains how it could be implemented within an Android app? Thanks.


Plus, it seems like it requires implementing software on both devices, yes?

Comment: Yes generally you need to implement on both sides. But in your case you just wanted to download the file so you can implement client alone and you can download Bluetooth FTP based applications which can act  as a server.

Comment: Below link  is the android bluetooth applcation source code where OPP profile(object push profile) using which files can be pushed to other devices.(Send via Bluetooth option is enabled through this service). This will be a good reference for implementing file transfer via bluetooth. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Bluetooth/+/android-5.1.1_r4/src/com/android/bluetooth/opp/

Comment: Thanks. However, the thing is the "server" part can't actually run any app apart from the launcher (it's an embedded device with no screen). I'll look into the link you gave, but it seems like it won't work this way...